# quartz crystal - figure of merit

Tags: circuit-analysis, oscillator

What represents this formula in terms of an RLC series circuit that forms a resonator? It is called figure of merit and it is defined like this:

M = 1/ w*C1*R1

where w = 2*pi*f

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the resonator Q?

Comment: yes, I edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation for figure of merit M, AKA the Q of the circuit, is correct as long as you recognize that \$f\$ is the resonant frequency, and \$C\$ is the capacitance that sets the resonant frequency.  In this case the resonant frequency is set by the motational capacitance and inductance, \$C_1\$ and \$L_1\$.

So \$\omega = \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1 L_1}}\$, and \$Q = \frac{1}{\omega C_1 R_1}\$.